# Angular & Firebase Realtime-Database. How to get child knowing its id property but without knowing its parent node

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Database is like this

[image]

I can get to cart part on my own and I can even delete the product from cart.. if I type in the auto generated id manually.. Honestly, I have been trying to do this for 2 days now. I researched every stackoverflow question related to firebase database but I still couldn't figure it out.

I get to cart like this: `firebase.database().ref('/' + account[0] + '_user' + '/cart')`

But I can't go further.. assume that I am also providing product that needs to get deleted and you can access its id through `item.id`

Right now if you click on delete button the whole cart gets deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the `product/id` property of the node to delete, you can use a query to order/filter the nodes and find the key of the one(s) you want to delete:

```
const cartRef = firebase.database().ref('/' + account[0] + '_user' + '/cart');

const itemQuery = cartRef.orderByChild("product/id").equalTo(3);

itemQuery.get().then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((productSnapshot) => {
    console.log(productSnapshot.key, productSnapshot.child("product/id").val());
  })
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
})
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer! But now it's giving me an error:

 cart.component.ts:54 Error: Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "product/id", for path "/_default_user/cart", to the rules

I can't add this rule for every account, right? or maybe I can? sorry I am new to all this, excuse my ignorance

Comment: Also I can't even properly set up rules.. https://imgur.com/a/AXmwslc

What is wrong with that? ( I know write:true is not safe but this is just for testing)

Comment: actually i figured it out. Thank you so much for the answer. For those wondering the solution to rules problem, I just nested it. I will figure out the 'multiple users' problem later